# views paging dropdown

Tags: views, paging

I need something like a drop down pager for a view with many pages.
Either drop down with all pages listed, or maybe more fancy like this one here:

http://www.zeit.de/2014/18/sextourismus-ostafrika/seite-5

(Scroll down to the comments part. Hovering the comments-pager pops up a grid with page-numbers)

Is there a module for that or an easy way to build it myself? I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For now I didn't find any module for this but you can achieve this by playing around with pager **CSS**. Just like drop down menus. **Pager** also has an unordered list with **ul** and **li**. I tried it and somehow I was able to show pager as a grid on hovering it and it was working. 
You have to do some more in it to achieve exactly what you want.

Here I have given you a rough idea and I think this will help you.